# How does this code of print of Python2.7 work?

Tags: python, printing

I'm learning python, and found a interesting example. I run this code, and the output a symbol of one of "/","-","|","\" and keep changing, I don't understand how exactly it works.

```
while True:
    for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:
        print "%s\r" % i,
```

Comment: `\r` is "carriage return". e.g. it moves the cursor back to the start of the line, so you print out `/`, then the cursor moves back, and overwrites the `/` with `-`, etc...

Comment: There's an infinite loop. On each iteration it goes through the list of symbols and print one of them with the `carriage return` escape character. So the new symbol is printed instead of an old one.

Comment: Those are both (parts of) answers, not comments.

Comment: And when I type any thing, another symbol shows up, then type again, and nothing happened, why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]` iterates the list element one by one.

`print "%s\r" % i,`   `\r` is carriage return, it reset the position to the beginning of the line.  `i,` is a `tuple` object here, it is equal to `(i,)` which is used with `%s` and `%` for string formatting.

`while True` is repeating above behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `for` loop is actually a `foreach` loop. So `for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:` iterates over each string in this list.

`print "%s\r" % i` prints `i` (which every iteration is a different string in the list) as `%s` (basic string formatting). The `/r` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.